# Using old alarm keypads as displays

Tags: gpio, home-automation, monitoring

I have a few old IDS alarm keypads lying around(both 8 and 16 zone) and was wondering if I could somehow hook them up to my pi.(LED only, no LCD)
Power can be supplied via the alarm panel, so I just need a way to interface with the keypad.
What would be even better(this is my actual goal) is to MITM the keypad, so the pi receives output from the alarm panel, processes it and then outputs to the keypad.

Comment: Welcome to raspberry pi SE. Sorry, what was the question?

Comment: Thanks @Bex.
I have a few old alarm system keypads which I want to hook up to my pi for output through the leds and for number input via the keypad: http://www.communica.co.za/Content/Catalog/Images/I1265054918.jpg and http://images.bidorbuy.co.za/user_images/620/2146620_120218200426_KEYPAD_816_LED.jpg . I have a few of both 16 and 8 zones